# My Timer won't tick c#

Tags: c#, timer

My timer won't tick, I've tried with printing to check if the timer is started, it starts but it never ticks. 
Here's the code:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 50;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        //Console.WriteLine("STARTING TIMER");
        timer.Start();
        NewFile();

    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TIMER TICKS");

        doc.MoveBalls(leftX, topY, width, height);
        doc.CheckCollision();
        Invalidate(true);

        Console.WriteLine("Moving2");
    }
```

Comment: Which .NET framework are you using? What timer are you using (namespace)?

Comment: @JuanIgnacioCornet System.Windows.Forms;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the answers given above, you may also use a thread of Timer which takes callback and a state object to keep your working thread safe like below

After you include the library before your namespace

```
using System.Threading;
```

// your namespace

```
        private readonly TimeSpan _updateInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        private Timer _timer = new Timer(CallBakFunction, null, _updateInterval, _updateInterval);
        private void CallBakFunction(object state)
        {

        }
```

In your case, this can be done as follows:

```
private readonly TimeSpan _updateInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
private Timer _timer ;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
  _timer = new Timer(timer_Tick, null, _updateInterval, _updateInterval);

    NewFile();

}
      private void timer_Tick(object state)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TIMER TICKS");

    doc.MoveBalls(leftX, topY, width, height);
    doc.CheckCollision();
    Invalidate(true);

    Console.WriteLine("Moving2");
}
```

I have updated a [final result video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxRMpaukAERwZjZwMzVKd0h2dm8) for your assistance please view this:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan _updateInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timer_Tick, null, _updateInterval, _updateInterval);

            NewFile();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void NewFile() { }
        private void timer_Tick(object state)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TIMER TICKS");

            //doc.MoveBalls(leftX, topY, width, height);
            //doc.CheckCollision();
            //Invalidate(true);

            Console.WriteLine("Moving2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error Timer constructor can be with one or zero arguments.

Comment: and where should i initialize system.windows.forms.timer??

Answer (score 1):

You enabled the timer before you attach the `OnTick` event. Setting `Enabled` to true is basically the same as `timer.Start()`. Remove the Enabled assignment, or replace the Start() call with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to work with winform

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 50;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        //Console.WriteLine("STARTING TIMER");
        timer.Start();

    }
```

Comment: I've changed and again it's not ticking

Comment: is it a winform application ?

Comment: maybe your problem is not for the timer, problem is somewhere else

Comment: Even if there is somewhere else problem, I am printing something in timer_tick and its not showing me in the output nothing.

Comment: yes I understand but the same code you posted here I have used in a winform application and it works fine here, so this code have no problem

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: hope you will able to find a solution